# No encuentra modulo cloudinary con Heroku

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, backend, heroku

el modulo cloudinary esta declarado y actualmente la app funciona perfecto en local, el tema es que quise subir el backend a heroku y me tira ese error y no se que es.

no me levanta es servidor, el backend lo tengo con babel para es6, crea una carpeta dist que amacena el index que se ejecuta con npm start

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec npx babel-node src/index.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist/",
    "build": "npm run clean && mkdir dist && babel src -s -d dist",
    "start": "node dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.18.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.30.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.0",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.3.1",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/node": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  }
}
```

tengo todas las variables declaradas, me da el ok cuando lo ejecuto en local pero cuando subo a servidor me tira error y no me deja desplegarlo.

este es mi Package.json y el error me lo da heroku diciendo..

```
Process exited with status 1
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688194+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688198+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688199+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688199+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688199+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../cloudinary.js'
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688200+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688200+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/dist/controllers/Product.controller.js
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688201+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/dist/routes/Product.routes.js
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688202+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/dist/index.js
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688203+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688204+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688204+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688205+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)      
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688206+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/dist/controllers/Product.controller.js:16:19)
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688206+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)   
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688208+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688208+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688208+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688209+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/dist/controllers/Product.controller.js',
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688209+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/dist/routes/Product.routes.js',
2022-06-21T22:42:34.688210+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/dist/index.js'
```

mi gitignore..

/node_modules
/dist
.env

mi estructura de datos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estos archivos se guardan en una carpeta que vos creas en local ?

Comment: No es local, sino dentro del servidor se crea una carpeta uploads pero cada vez que se sube se elimina de la carpeta para no usar espacio extra ya que se guarda en cloudinary

Comment: El servidor es nube, servidor compartido o con acceso a root total ? (Yo estoy hablando de las pruebas que haces en local, no del fallo)

Comment: [Lectura recomendada](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#don-t-check-in-generated-directories). Adicionalmente podrías compartir tu `.gitignore` y tu estructura de archivos.

Comment: compartido, la carpeta se crea dentro del repositorio que que directamente se sube a heroku

Comment: Perfecto... Heroku es como la nube digamos. vos no podes crear carpetas para un storage. lo que tenes que hacer para guardar cosas (archivos) es usar un storage aparte.

Comment: y como lo guardo ? en el storage del navegador podria ser ? o sino donde ?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar algun servicio que provea storage o simplemente usar un servidor con acceso a root

Comment: @ricardo-dlc ahi te subi el gitignore y la estructura de datos